# Is it possible to deposit or cash this check?

Tags: united-states, banking, check, endorsement

I have a check made out to 3 people, with "and" separating our names. I managed to get all 3 to endorse said check but the bank won't allow me to deposit it without everyone present which just isn't possible. Is there any bank that would allow me to cash or deposit the check or somehow get the funds? My apartment complex refuses to recut a check to change the wording to "or" so if I can't deposit this, I can't get my security deposit back. (This is in the US, I've tried Commerce Bank, First Bank, and Regions Bank)

Comment: Since you say "deposit", try **depositing** the check in a bank where you have an account in _your_ name, preferably with no co-owners. DO NOT ask for any money back from the deposit.  _Your_ bank will likely put a hold on the money deposited until the check clears.

Comment: If all tenants give legal permission to the apartment complex to return the security deposit to a certain person, they *should* do as requested.

Comment: As someone with first hand experience on this, if everyone has endorsed it and you are depositing it only then there is zero issue and any bank would accept it. Something that has been already raised by @DilipSarwate

Comment: Deposit it in your ATM, wait for it to clear.

Comment: I've already tried depositing it. No bank will accept it without every party present. At least not when I speak to a teller. Other sites recommend NOT using ATMs to deposit such checks because it will likely not accept it and it may take months to return to me and there would likely be a fine attached for trying to do so.

Comment: Sigh. Banks seem to forget that a **negotiable instrument** is **negotiable**. In hindsight, maybe you could have entered a more explicit endorsement: "Pay to the order of zem" and had everyone sign. That's how checks are supposed to work.

Answer (score 8):

Avoid talking to a person:  Just use an automated system, such as an ATM or a cellphone app.  Automated systems will ONLY scan for the RTN # and Account number at the bottom of the check (the funny looking blocky numbers).

The automated system will not care who the check is made out to, or who is present, so long as you have an account to credit the money into, and the account number on the check can get the money debited properly.